# How to group table cell together so we can hide them with one statement? (webforms)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a table with 2 set of cells in the first row each set containing 5 cells. Each cell contains controls inside them.

My issue is, if a certain condition is true, I need to hide one set and show the other and vice versa when the condition is false. Currently I have 10 .Visible =  statements in my code for true part, and 10 for the false part. Is there any way to `group` one set of cells together so that hiding the group can hide all 5? I have to do it all in server-side code, no jQuery.

```
<table>
<tr>
<!-- first set -->
<td runat="server" id="set1_cell1"> content here</td>
<td runat="server" id="set1_cell2"> content here</td>
<td runat="server" id="set1_cell3"> content here</td>
<td runat="server" id="set1_cell4"> content here</td>
<td runat="server" id="set1_cell5"> content here</td>
<!-- end first set -->


<!-- second set -->
<td runat="server" id="set2_cell1"> content here</td>
<td runat="server" id="set2_cell2"> content here</td>
<td runat="server" id="set2_cell3"> content here</td>
<td runat="server" id="set2_cell4"> content here</td>
<td runat="server" id="set2_cell5"> content here</td>
<!-- end second set -->
</tr>
...
</table>
```

This is how my current code looks like

```
if (condition is true)
{
 set1_cell1.Visible = true;
 set1_cell2.Visible = true;
 set1_cell3.Visible = true;
 set1_cell4.Visible = true;
 set1_cell5.Visible = true;

 set2_cell1.Visible = false;
 set2_cell2.Visible = false;
 set2_cell3.Visible = false;
 set2_cell4.Visible = false;
 set2_cell5.Visible = false;
}
else
{
  // opposite of the above
}
```

I would love to replace those 10 statements with just one.

Comment: Are there other cells in the row?

Answer (score 2):

You can give a different class name to the cells of each group:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row1" runat="server">
        <td class="set1">Content 1a</td>
        <td class="set1">Content 1b</td>
        <td class="set1">Content 1c</td>
        <td class="set1">Content 1d</td>
        <td class="set1">Content 1e</td>

        <td class="set2">Content 2a</td>
        <td class="set2">Content 2b</td>
        <td class="set2">Content 2c</td>
        <td class="set2">Content 2d</td>
        <td class="set2">Content 2e</td>

        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

In code-behind, you show/hide the cells according to the class name and the value of the condition:

```
foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in row1.Cells)
{
    string className = cell.Attributes["class"];

    if (className == "set1")
    {
        cell.Visible = condition;
    }

    if (className == "set2")
    {
        cell.Visible = !condition;
    }
}
```

Note 1: The class name could also be used to do the same on the client side if you want to (especially with jQuery).

Note 2: I use the class name in the code above but you could get the same result with a custom attribute (e.g. `data-group="set1"` instead of `class="set1"`, with the corresponding change in code-behind).

Comment: @fahadash - Did you have a chance to try this solution?